# Retrieve Image from Amazon S3 by C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

Is there any tutorial video or website about how to retrieve the data from Amazon S3 by using C# MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

namespace s3.amazon.com.docsamples
{
    class GetObject
    {
        static string bucketName = "*** bucket name ***";
        static string keyName    = "*** object key ***";
        static IAmazonS3 client;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieving (GET) an object");
            string data = ReadObjectData();
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                              s3Exception.InnerException);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string ReadObjectData()
    {
        string responseBody = "";

        using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) 
        {
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest 
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName
            };

            using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))  
            using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
                Console.WriteLine("The object's title is {0}", title);

                responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return responseBody;
    }
}
}
```

For Further Reference [Click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html)